# Plot rows of dataframe for comparison

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have data in the following format as attached. So basically for each test data, I have 10 observation from different models.

[image]

Now, I want to compare the variability of the observations in the way as shown below. So that the center point represents mean of all the observations and all values are shown as box plot around it. Something like this figure below. Here the center green dot represents mean and the line shows the obs_1, obs_2 till obs_10.

[image]

I am able to draw only simple box plot post transforming the data but it does not seem to be visually appealing and hence trying something like this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot you showed is more like a CI plot.. not a boxplot. And it's not clear what the bars represent, 95% confidence of the mean? So not quite sure what you want.

Let's say your data is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(15,10)),
                  columns = ['obs_'+ str(i) for i in np.arange(1,11)])
```

A boxplot of each row can be done:

```
df.T.boxplot()
```

[image]

95% CI of the mean:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.pointplot(x="index", y="value",
 data=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars="index"), join=False)
```

[image]

To add some other points, for example the `obs_1` column :

```
ax.scatter(x = df.index , y= df['obs_1'],c = "k")
```

Comment: Thanks man! , so basically it means that seaborn default way of lineplot is using CI. Also, in addition, suppose one of the observation is the actual value here.. Can we plot that actual value in the same above graph in different color?